# java oracle create upsert query based on 2 keys from ArrayList

Tags: java, oracle, arraylist

I have a simple ArrayList that holds the same data types from my oracle DB.

```
public class routesData {
    private String pKey; // pk
    private String sKey; // sec key
    private String data; // data
}
```

And its ArrayList:

```
ArrayList <routesData> dataList;
```

The list gets updated every hour and, sometime with new keys.
I want to make `upsert` query that will check if `pKey` and `sKey` exsits in the table, if so update `data`, if not then create a new row.
How do I iterate over `dataList` and run `Merge` query for each entry?
Here is my best try, still I get `ORA-00001` for uplicated key.

```
MERGE INTO m_tableName n
   USING (dataList.get(i).getpKey, dataList.get(i).getsKey) S
   ON (n.pkey == dataList.get(i).getpKey && n.sKey == dataList.get(i).getsKey)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET (n.data = dataList.get(i).getData)

   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT INTO m_tableName(dataList.get(i).getpKey, dataList.get(i).getsKey, dataList.get(i).getData)
```

- I defined that the table have 2 `primary keys` -  `pKey, sKey` if it require a change I will do so.